# Can I link a layout/view class to an XML item

Tags: java, android, android-layout

What I am trying to achieve (which I do not know if it is even doable, since I'm new to android development) is to have:

1. A MainActivity class utilize/reference and XML layout (this i know is doable)
2. Within the MainActivity class also call a custom Layout programmatically (I am uncertain how to do this)

To elaborate on my question

I have the following XML layout which is compromised of two items:

1. A dropdown menu
2. A RelativeLayout view (*** this is where I would like to link to my custom class to)

Here is the XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/weekDropdown"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
            android:hint="@string/select_week"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:labelFor="@+id/weekSelected">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/weekSelected"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="none"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:padding="14dp"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


        <RelativeLayout                                        <-- Here is where I would like to link my custom class
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

       </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

In my custom class, I build my layout/view programmatically:

```
public class MainActivityLayout extends RelativeLayout {

    Context context;

    TableLayout tableA;
    TableLayout tableB;
    TableLayout tableC;
    TableLayout tableD;

    public MainActivityLayout(Context context) {
    
        super(context);
    
        this.initComponents();

        this.setComponentsId();

        etc... 

    }

}
```

Which I call it from my `MainActivity` class like so:

```
setContentView(new MainActivityLayout(this));
```

So is it possible to link the RelativeLayout in the XML to my custom class? If so can you let me know how to do so?

Comment: Is there a reason to use a custom view? It is not a simple as you think -- to implementing it correctly (wrap_content, match_parent, absolute size, etc..).

Comment: I have put alot of effort in creating the custom view and its working as desired... i just need the "new" element which is the dropdown menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use your custom view, the easiest way is to include it in the xml. So this needs to be changed:

```xml
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
</RelativeLayout>
```

into this

```xml
<myapp.mypackage.MainActivityLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
</myapp.mypackage.MainActivityLayout>
```

Change `myapp.mypackage` based on the real path of `MainActitvityLayout`.

Then just use it like any other usual layouts.

```java
setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
```

Also you must override these constructors:

```java
public MainActivityLayout(Context context)
{
    super(context);
}

public MainActivityLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
}

public MainActivityLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr)
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

public MainActivityLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes)
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
}
```

However, if you insist on using it like this:

```java
setContentView(new MainActivityLayout(this));
```

You can not use the main xml layout at all, but you can still inflate xml files onto your custom view. I won't write them here, you can easily search on this site on how implementing them.